# In NetLogo, what is the most efficient way to copy the values of variables in an agentset to another agentset with the same number of agents

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo, I have the same number of turtles on different patches. Now I want to copy the agent variable values of the agents on one patch to those agents on another patch. I know I can define a list of members for each patch, and then copy the values agent by agent according to the order of the list, but I have to define a list for each patch, which may take some memory and reduce the running speed.

In other words, I want the agents on one patch with their agent variable values the same as the agents on another patch.

Are there more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: Do the turtles on the 'receiving' patch have any variables other than the ones being copied, or are they expected to be exact duplicates of the turtles to be copied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like this **hatch** makes exact duplicates of the original turtles same variables same color etc
targ is the patch you want them at

```
to dup-turtles-to [targ]
ask turtles-here 
[
hatch 1 [move-to targ]
]
end
```

I hope that is helpful and I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes, it can achieve what I want. But in this case, I need to have the old turtles "die" at targ, right? Is this more efficient than copying the values of the variables?

Comment: you have to kill them if you don't want two sets of with identical values. if you want only one set the best thing to do is just move them to the patch you want them on.

Comment: You can use `move-to targ` instead of `set xcor [pxcor] of targ set ycor [pycor] of targ` in this answer.

Comment: should I revise my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't make it clear. The new target patch has the same number of other turtles, and I want the turtles on the new patch have variable values the same as the turtles in the "source" patch. Both of these two groups of turtles are always there, and I just want one group to have exactly the same variable values.

Comment: well that is a stickier problem. I am not sure but kill and copy might be  more efficient. it certainly is code-wise